# Localization for library project without any activity in android

Tags: android

I have a library project say "SampleLibrary" which has only java files and does not have any activity in it. And i am using this library in my application say "Sample". I have a method as follows in "Sample Library".

```
 public boolean load(String filePathName )
    {
        String Work;
        Work = GetString( "Sample", No , "", filePathName );
        if( 0 == Work.length())
        {
            Work = GetString( "サンプル", No, "", filePathName);
        }
     }
```

Now i want customize this code to get the string value from String.xml or by anoy other means. To use getString(R.String.sample) i need a context. but i don't have any activity in my library.

can any one, please help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create subclass of Application and set the `android:name` attribute of your `<application>` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Now in your class you can use application context like this.

```
MyApplication.getContext().getResources()
```

Comment: You should never declare Application in a library

Comment: Thans for your reply..this doesn't work. i used like thisMyApplication.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.sample). It throws nullpointerException.

Comment: thisMyApplication is your Application extended class name? have you set android:name =thisMyApplication" in manifest? @Zielony

Comment: this is my manifest file. Still i am getting the same error.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.SampleApp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      android:name =".MyApplication" 
      >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

</manifest>

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable solution is to provide a simple init method with Context as a parameter. It's not possible to access Resources from a static context. You can't use Application as well as your code is enclosed in a library.